# (In the choice of people that was made in the Gideon story), why were those who bowed down upon their knees to drink water rejected? Judges 7:5-6

Tags: shoftim--book-of, bowing-kneeling, gideon

Is there anything wrong with bowing down upon the knees to get anything (fulfill a need, even a basic need as drink water is)(given that you can do it by avoiding the "bowing down upon your knees" position)?

> So he brought down the people unto the water: and the Lord said unto Gideon, Every one that lappeth of the water with his tongue, as a dog lappeth, him shalt thou set by himself; likewise every one that boweth down upon his knees to drink. And the number of them that lapped, putting their hand to their mouth, were three hundred men: but all the rest of the people bowed down upon their knees to drink water. Judges 7:5-6

Answer (score 2):

[Rashi says](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.7.5?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he) that

> those who kneeled were accustomed to kneel before idols.
>
> כי הם לא ילכו עמך, שכך הם למודים לכרוע לפני עבודת גלולים:

[The Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.7.4?lang=he&with=Radak&lang2=he) has a similar view

> כי הכורעים על ברכיהם לשתות היה סימן לאשר כרעו לבעל

and quotes a Medrash

> that they might be instead be worshipping their reflections
>
> ובמדרש אתה מוצא בימי גדעון שהיו עובדין לבבואה שלהם אותם שהיו כורעין על
>   ברכיהן פירוש לצל שהיה נראה מהם על המים:

Hashem gave this test to Gideon which would indicate that **these people** should not be taken with him. It is not clear to me that this is a definite indication that bowing down upon your knees is always wrong.